# How do I change the final location of a compiled c program in the terminal

Tags: c, compilation-target

After a c program is compiled it is stored in `./a.out`.

Is there any way in which I can change the file to any name I want?

Comment: Location or file name, which?

Comment: the file name  of the compiled program

Comment: What command do you run for it to be saved as ./a.out?

Comment: gcc (the file name ).c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the compiler. For the GCC family (`gcc`, `g++`, etc.), you can use the `-o` option. The following creates an executable name `blah`:

```
gcc foo.c -o blah
```

Comment: +1 `clang` and `clang++` maintain this convention AFAIK